# Git size too large to upload to github. All branches except master were deleted, all files cleared

Tags: git, github, git-bash

1. I have deleted all branches except master in my local repo.
2. I have ran two of these commands:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

3. I switched to SSH connection

But still my local repo is too large even thought the main volume of it is in `.git` folder (4.7 Gb), all the rest files are (150-250 Mb) and I can't push it to remote `github.com` repository.

And of course I got this error: `remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size`

How can I push it to remote repository?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, it’s not possible to push more than 2GB to GitHub.com at a time. For cases like this, I would recommend pushing the repository up in ‘chunks’ of commits:

```
git push <remotename> <commit SHA>:<remotebranchname>
```

This command will push up to and including all commits before the commit specified in the command. I suggest running `git log --pretty=oneline` and choosing a commit half way or so down the list. Once this is pushed you should be able to run another git push to add the rest of the commits depending on the total size of the pushes.

P.S: You can also try https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ BFG REPO Cleaner first before commiting